# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file

Tags: java, apache, mirth

I am working on Linux for Mitrh and when I shutdown Apache server it gives following error:

[image: ./shutdown.sh]

**And when I check for filesystem-**

[image: File System]

**I dont know how to use /dev/sdb1/ that is 99% available**

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late. But, changing the tmp file location to a place with more space for JVM could solve your problem:

```
export JAVACMD_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/temp/directory/with/more/space";
```

Hope this helps